# Bootstrap tooltips and popover do not seem to ever work on anything i develop

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

I developed a bootstrap site and wanted to use tooltip or popover with images.

But Ive met failures. The tooltip is never customized, it comes out as raw text. I dont know why.

I stopped everything I was doing and went over to http://reecegeorge.com/bootstrap-popovers.html to learn tooltips/popover from scratch.

I ended up with the same result even after copying their examples word for word.

See the screen shots of my outputs and pleas help me.

Ive hosted the site at http://digitex.ovh You may open it and hover on the top images, its a shame. You can check the source code directly too.

I want to know what Im doing wrong.

I use EasyPHP as my local server. (Though my work is only bootstrap + JS)

Thank you

Check the two images here, remove the spaces inbetween and add http:// to the front

i. stack. imgur. com/2sydp. jpg
 i. stack. imgur. com/Dfyby. jpg

Comment: Looking in the console it seems that you include jQuery after the script tag where :

$(document).ready(function(){

        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   

    });

So this <script> tag should go at the end of page. Or even better in some .js file.

Comment: So I should use the script at the bottom of the page. like before i end the body tag.

Comment: Yes, you should use this after you load jquery and bootstrap javascript files.

Comment: @RajeevKumarsingh  Im almost fed up with what Im doing on this site. The site I built seem to have a lag. I have to refresh the site 3 to 4 times before I can get the proper display. But even after the proper display, popover doesnt show up anymore. I dont have the problem while using local host, but once I upload it to the webserver and enter http://digitex.ovh, the problems surface. What am I doing wrong, or what do I need to improve. I will like the site not to be changing layout during loading and after loading. If possible the page should load progressively, not all images and then layout

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely have a popover containing any valid html.

```
HTML:

<div class="container">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" 
           data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title">
       Custom Popover (Hover over me)
   </button>
```

```
JS:

$(document).ready(function(){
    var options = {
        html: true,
        trigger: 'hover',
        placement: 'bottom',
        content: "<div style='text-align:center;'>
                    <img src='http://placehold.it/200x100'>
                    <div>This is a popover content with image. 
                        it can have any valid html :-)
                    </div>
                  </div>"
    };    
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(options);
});
```

Here is a fiddle for this:

https://jsfiddle.net/callicoder/hvwh75nL/

For more information, refer http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

Comment: Kumar, Ill try the steps you gave here, including copying your solution word for word.

Comment: Also, as suggested by Nemanja Popovic, use your script in the bottom of the document after jquery is loaded. (Look at the console for the error - Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined). This is because you are trying to use $ before jquery is loaded.

Comment: I really appreciate you guys. I copied this script you gave me into the main.js file in the js folder instead of merely pasting it into the footer or header of the site. And now it worked. Thumbs up for you!!!! Rajeev